# Windows 7 - extending path variable by another entry leads to failure

Tags: windows-7, path

I experience a very strange problem. I have the following path variable.

`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Users\Robert\Programme\youtube-dl;C:\Users\Robert\Programme\sqlite`

With this variable all goes fine and I can executes commands such as sqlite. However, once I append `;C:\Users\Robert\Programme\FFmpeg\bin` to it I cannot run any command that is on that path anymore, such as sqlite.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Regards

Comment: I was tempted to blame the maximum length, but since you are on Windows 7, that *should* be 8191 characters.  The current path appears to be about ~1400 characters.  Ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473

Comment: Does Windows handle duplicate command conflicts? Maybe that is somehow triggering the issue.

Comment: I deleted all the double entries which somehow seemed to resolve the problem. Regards

Comment: @orschiro: why not put your last comment as answer and flag it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all the double entries which somehow seemed to resolve the problem.